# How to make a loop for a link text that has only one digit present so as to navigate through pages?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to navigate through the pages that have href as:

```
href="/Amazon-com-Amazon-Appstore/product-reviews/B071NZZHF9/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_2?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=critical&pageNumber=2&pageSize=10"
```

and link text as '2' which keeps on changing corresponding to the page i wany to navigate.

i have total of 6 pages and for that i wanted to make a for loop so that i dont have to give the href again and again.

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: its alright i already got my answer and the program is running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = 2; j <= 5; j++) { WebDriverWait pagechange_star = new WebDriverWait(dr,20);
                        pagechange_star.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cm_cr-pagination_bar']/ul/li["+j+"]/a")));
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cm_cr-pagination_bar']/ul/li["+j+"]/a")).click();
}
```

so j is a variable here which will increase its value from 2 to 5. hence we can scroll through different pages using it in the xpath.

Comment: so j is a variable here which will increase its value from 2 to 5. hence we can scroll through different pages using it in the xpath.